# Library Linking errors in Linux: symbol lookup error :RegisterGlobalAtExitNotification

Tags: linux, opencl, intel

I get the following runtime error on Linux.

/opt/intel/opencl-1.2-6.4.0.25/lib64/libclang_compiler.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: RegisterGlobalAtExitNotification (fatal)

Which library should I link with to resolve these errors?

Comment: Are you using LLVM? Do you have the same error with GCC?

Comment: @gj13 We use clang++ 3.7. I have no way of testing this with GCC. Thanks.